# SourceGuardian Error

Tags: php, http, encoding

**Error printed to screen:**

> Fatal error: SourceGuardian Loader - script checksum error [12] Encoded script was modified in /home/user/public_html/domain_com/includes_encoded/params.php on line 2

**Facts:**

Using a Hostgator host which have SourceGuardian loaders already in place, phpinfo also confirms they are loaded.

Using demo version of SourceGuardian.

Questions:

- Do I need to upload some license key file?
- Is there any special tag to include encoded files into pages?
- How do I fix it?

I read documentation all over PDF and online. Don't know where my problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused because the Demo Version uses Demo Loaders and not the full loaders which where used by the host.